# Anchoring of link from ToC to Chapter not showing chapter title

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, anchor

My main issue is the anchoring of a `chapter` link: When clicking on the chapter from the ToC, the anchor puts the line below the chapter title at the top of your page. This results in not being able to see the chapter title itself.[image] [image]

Any help would be appreciated

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fullpage}  
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!80!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

%% Spacing 
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\smallskip\bfseries}%\vspace{1cm}%
{}%
{\itshape\bfseries}%numberless%
{\hfill\contentspage}%
\titlecontents{section}[4.25em]{\smallskip}%
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2em}}%numbered
{\hspace{-1em}}
{\hfill\contentspage}%

%Misc
\lstset{breaklines, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\centering\color{BrickRed}}{}{0pt}{\LARGE}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-75pt}{\parskip}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000} 
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\frontmatter{\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{ \cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \setcounter{chapter}{-1}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \chapter{The First Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: shorten your document. It is not okay to dump your whole preamble and let others spent their time to figure out what is important and what not. That is your job. Try it out: remove a package or some code and if the problem is still there it is not relevant. continue until the preamble has a reasonable size.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, I have reduced it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the chapter titles to the header area while the link will go to the textarea.

[image: a]

With `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-25pt}{\parskip}`

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry} %  show the margins
\usepackage{listings}
 %\usepackage{fullpage} % do not use 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!80!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

%% Spacing 
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\smallskip\bfseries}%\vspace{1cm}%
{}%
{\itshape\bfseries}%numberless%
{\hfill\contentspage}%
\titlecontents{section}[4.25em]{\smallskip}%
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2em}}%numbered
{\hspace{-1em}}
{\hfill\contentspage}%

%Misc
\lstset{breaklines, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\centering\color{BrickRed}}{}{0pt}{\LARGE}[\titlerule]

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-25pt}{\parskip} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000} 
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\frontmatter{\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{ \cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \setcounter{chapter}{-1}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    Some text
    \chapter{The First Chapter}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow up question

If you have no use for the header area suppress the top margin.

`\usepackage[top=0in,bottom=1in, left=1in, right= 1in,  showframe]{geometry}`

and remove the package `fullpage`.

[image: c]

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Is there no way to move the pointer to the header area if the title is there? If it's too complicated compared to this solution, I'm okay with accepting this

Comment: @Hushus46 Thank you for your feedback! Please see the updated answer. If for some reason you need to put the chapter title into the header area please make another question on this topic.

Comment: Thank you. This is fine